# Uncaught ReferenceError: Factory is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to set up a sample Angular.js project with MVC.

I had the project simply returning a message from the controller. However when I tried to read back from a WebApi into a factory I am getting the following error at run time.

```
 AngularTutorial?v=exNgsrzkUJRjHARMvxI_00QqlywTra533io1LcIemD81:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: HomeFactory is not defined(anonymous function) @ AngularTutorial?v=exNgsrzkUJRjHARMvxI_00QqlywTra533io1LcIemD81:1
    angular.js:11655 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: HomeFactoryProvider <- HomeFactory <- HomeController
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=HomeFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20HomeFactory%20%3C-%20HomeController
        at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
        at angular.js:4015
        at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4162)
        at angular.js:4020
        at getService (angular.js:4162)
        at Object.invoke (angular.js:4194)
        at $get.extend.instance (angular.js:8493)
        at angular.js:7739
        at forEach (angular.js:331)
        at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7738)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11655$get @ angular.js:8596$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:14567bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1455invoke @ angular.js:4203doBootstrap @ angular.js:1453bootstrap @ angular.js:1473angularInit @ angular.js:1367(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26304trigger @ angular.js:2762eventHandler @ angular.js:3032
```

Here are the files that seem to be causing the issue.

AngularTutorial.js

```
var AngularTutorial = angular.module('AngularTutorial', []);

AngularTutorial.controller('HomeController', HomeController);

AngularTutorial.factory('HomeFactory', HomeFactory);
```

HomeFactory.js

```
var HomeFactory = function($http, $q) {
    return function() {
        var deferredResult = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://localhost:52506/api/message/get')
            .success(function(data) {
                deferredResult.resolve(data);
            });
        return deferredResult.promise;
    }
}
HomeFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
```

HomeController

```
var HomeController = function ($scope, HomeFactory) {

    HomeFactory().then(function(response) {
        $scope.message = response;
    });
}
HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'HomeFactory'];
```

I have included a link to the entire solution if that is any help.

[Project Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0beCxD_vRpPbFotamxHV1QyNTg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Look into the order of the files you added into the AngularTutorial.js... ACtually it should be `var AngularTutorial = angular.module('AngularTutorial', []);
AngularTutorial.factory('HomeFactory', HomeFactory);
AngularTutorial.controller('HomeController', HomeController);

`

Answer (score 0):

see the below sample

```js
var AngularTutorial = angular.module('AngularTutorial', []);

AngularTutorial.factory('HomeFactory', [
  '$http',
  '$q',
  function($http, $q) {
    return function() {
      return $http.get('http://localhost:52506/api/message/get');
    }
  }
]);


AngularTutorial.controller('HomeController', [
  '$scope',
  'HomeFactory',
  function($scope, HomeFactory) {
    HomeFactory().then(function(response) {
      $scope.message = response;
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="AngularTutorial">
  <div ng-controller="HomeController">
    {{message}}
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no need of creating `deferred` object in factory. `$http.get` also return promise only So, you can simply return `$http.get(/*URL*/)`.